# How to use OAuth2Credential in asp.net MVC web application

Tags: oauth-2.0, youtube-data-api

I have used OAuth2Credential in my asp.net MVC application for uploading a video to youtube channel. its working fine when I run the application directly. But when I publish the application and browse from IIS, the OAuth2Credential is coming as null.

Please help me on this.

Comment: You probably should and a code sample for this.

Comment: Be as precise as possible when adding tags.